# Flow error when using ref in react-native

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I use `ref` to be able to tab through a from in a `<ScrollView>`
The code works but i keep getting this flow error

```
Cannot assign input to this.inputs.emailInput because null [1] is 
incompatible with object literal [2].

 src/authentication/containers/SignIn.js
[ .2] 105│     emailInput: {},
    :
 199│             }}
 200│             placeholder={I18n.t('email')}
 201│             ref={(input) => {
 202│               this.inputs.emailInput = input;
 203│             }}
 204│             returnKeyType={'next'}
 205│             style={styles.textInput}

 /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_3c65178/react.js
[1] 184│   | ((React$ElementRef<ElementType> | null) => mixed)
```

Here is concerned code

definition of inputs:
inside my react component

```
inputs= {
  lastNameInput: {},
  emailInput: {},
  postalCodeInput: {},
  phoneNumberInput: {},
};
```

a `<TextInput>` element in the `render()` function :

```
<TextInput
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ lastName: text })}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          this.inputs.emailInput.focus();
        }}
        placeholder={I18n.t('lastName')}
        ref={(input) => this.inputs.lastNameInput = input}
        returnKeyType={'next'}
        style={styles.textInput}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        value={lastName}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the `ref` callback can pass null to your provided function. I believe it does this when the referenced component is unmounted.